# Dojo script not executing on iPad when async = true

Tags: ipad, mobile, asynchronous, dojo

I have a simple test page (below) that I'm trying to display on an iPad. The page simply loads a couple Dojo mobile modules and shows an alert box. The alert box pops up, and the mobile device theme is applied, maybe 1 time out of every 10 or 20 page refreshes. However, if I turn async off the alert is displayed every time the page is refreshed.

Is there some incompatibility between Dojo's asynchronous loading mode and mobile devices that I'm not aware of, or have I structure this code incorrectly in some way?

I'm using the un-minified version of Dojo 1.7.1 and serving the page with Django's development server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lange="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" 
          content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/> 
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/> 
    <title>Testing Stuff</title>

    <script>
      dojoConfig = {
          parseOnLoad: true,
          async: true
      };
    </script>
    <script src="/static/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="heading">Mobile!</h1>
    <script>
      require(['dojox/mobile',
               'dojox/mobile/deviceTheme'], function() {
        dojo.ready(function() {
          alert('hello');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I believe I found the answer to my own question. According to [Django dev ticket 3357](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3357), the Django development server (runserver) is single threaded, so it can't handle multiple simultaneous requests. Putting Dojo's loader into asynchronous mode makes multiple simultaneous requests, so that's likely the source of the problem.

The long and short of it is that using Dojo with `async` enabled is not a supported use case for the Django development server.